# No carga mapa en DIV con Geolocalización API de Google

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

tengo un problema para que me muestre el mapa de google, he intentado en diferentes dispositivos y no se visualiza.

No se mucho sobre Javascript, he estado intentando hacer que la dirección se cargue desde un minimap con un marker, buscando por internet e intentando con varios códigos, no cargaba ninguno.
PD: Para esta función utiliza permisos de ubicación, pero mi dispositivo ya lo tiene permitido. Espero de antemanto que alguien me pueda ayudar. Saludos cordiales!

```js
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MI_KEY]&sensor=false"></script>


if(navigator.geolocation){
var success = function(position){
var latitud3 = position.coords.latitude,
    longitud3 = position.coords.longitude;

        var map;
        var marker;
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitud3, longitud3);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Mapa"), mapOptions);
            var marker;
              google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
              placeMarker(event.latLng);
            });



        function placeMarker(location) {
            if (marker == null)
            {
                  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    zoom:20
                  });
            }
            else
            {
                marker.setPosition(location);
            }
            geocoder.geocode(
                { location: location },
                (
                  results = google.maps.GeocoderResult,
                  status= google.maps.GeocoderStatus
                ) => {
                  if (status === "OK") {
                    if (results[0]) {
                  console.log  (results[0].address_components);
                   var address_components = results[0].address_components;
                            var components={};
                            jQuery.each(address_components,function(k,v1) {jQuery.each(v1.types,function(k2, v2){components[v2]=v1.long_name});});
                            var city, postal_code,state,country,sublocality,street_number,route;
                             
                            console.log(components);
                            if(components.locality) {
                                city = components.locality;
                            }
     
                            if(!city) {
                                city = components.administrative_area_level_1;
                            }
     
                            if(components.postal_code) {
                                postal_code = components.postal_code;
                            }
                            if(components.postal_code) {
                                postal_code = components.postal_code;
                            }
     
                            if(components.administrative_area_level_1) {
                                state = components.administrative_area_level_1;
                            }
                             
                            if(components.route) {
                                route = components.route;
                            }
                            if(components.sublocality_level_1) {
                                sublocality = components.sublocality_level_1;
                            }
                            if(components.country) {
                                country = components.country;
                            }
                            if(components.street_number) {
                              street_number = components.street_number;
                            }
                            $('#direccion').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                            
                   
                    } else {
                      window.alert("No results found");
                    }
                  } else {
                    window.alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                  }
                }
              );
        }
 
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        }
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, function(msg){
console.error( msg );
});
}
```

```html
<input type="text" disabled="" name="direccion" id="direccion" class="form-control" placeholder="Dirección y número de casa" required="">
<div id="Mapa" width="100%" style="height: 280px;"></div>
<small>Por favor, presione la ubicacion de su domicilio sobre el mapa.</small>
```

Al ejecutar el script no me manda ningún error en la consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En donde estas ejecutando??

Comment: @DavElsanto Si te refieres a lo del script, veo si hay algún error desde la consola de google chrome

Comment: No me refiero a que framework estás usando